# Regex if certain string is included between particular HTML tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the below html as a text string

```
<p>I'll write a H1 below</p>
<h1>Hi I'm H1</h1>
<p>Last p</p>
```

What i want to do is see if 'I'm H1' exists in the h1 tag - curious as to what the regex above would be so that it returns true

P.S: Even if it contained `<h1>I'm H1 buddy</h1>` it should return true so essentially in a h1 tag, if it contains a particular string, in the above case 'I'm H1', it should output true

Comment: If it is the plain regex you want, then here it is, `\<h1\>.(I'm H1).\</h1\>`. It will work if the whole thing is a string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @VinodKumar Did you try that?  Doesn't work for the example provided (there's no character after the "I'm H1" to match the . and only matches one character before.   Could be SO removing '*' ?

Comment: I am sorry, my mistake. I did not try. This should work `\<h1\>.*?(I'm H1).*?\<\/h1\>`

Comment: Not sure why this was tagged with javascript, but that's why you're getting javascript answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex should work:

```
<h1>.*I'm H1.*<\/h1>
```

That's `<h1>` followed by optional text (`.*`), followed by "I'm H1", followed by more optional text (`.*`), followed by `</h1>`.

Demonstration on [Online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/gG3eO8/1).

Comment: thanks, this is the simplest way to do it and it just works - one question regarding escaping - the keyword i'm trying to test with is a variable - say 'var keyword' with a particular value and the following does not work: new RegExp("/<h1>.*?" + "http redirect 302" + ".*?<\/h1>/gi").test(plainHtml)

Comment: pretty sure i'm not escaping it properly but don't know what the right way to do it is

Answer (score 1):

It is a way to solve your problem with Regex.

```js
var re = /<h1>.*?\sI'm\sH1.*?<\/h1>/; 
var str = '<p>I\'ll write a H1 below</p>\n<h1>Hi I\'m H1 buddy</h1>\n<p>Last p</p>';
var m;
 
if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}

document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = m != null
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: And what happen if the OP add buggy?

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>.*?I'm\sH1.*?</h1>
```

- `.*?` any or none characters with minimum match (so doesn't match multiple H1s)
- `\s` for any whitespace
- `I'm\sH1` literal

Edit: no need to escape `<` and `>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
/(I'm H1)/.test("Hi I'm H1") // return true
/(I'm H1)/.test("Hi I'm H1 buddy") // return true
```

Answer (score -1):

Is there a reason you need a regex?

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML.indexOf("Hi I'm H1") != -1) 
{ 

}
```